# Why does the parity of a meson have a "+1" in it?

Tags: particle-physics, conventions, parity, mesons

The [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)) of a meson is defined as $ P = (-1)^{L+1} $ where $L$ is the angular momentum.
What does the "1" in the exponent represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will consider mesons, as requested in a comment.

We need to consider both the intrinsic parity and the "regular" parity:

$$ \pi_\text{total} = \pi_\text{intrinsic} \times\pi $$

Since a meson contains a quark and an antiquark, the intrinsic parity is $\pi_\text{intrinsic}=-1$. This is because particle and antiparticle have opposite intrinsic parities. Whether you assign the particle $+1$ or $-1$ does not matter since $(+1)(-1)=(-1)(+1)=-1$.

As for the "regular" parity, we need to investigate the corresponding spherical harmonic of the wave function. This is $(-1)^L$.

Now, together:

$$ \pi = (-1) \times (-1)^L = (-1)^{L+1} $$

For more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Parity).